# create pyspark dataframe from nested list

Tags: pyspark

I need to create a dataframe from nested list

I have tried different methods, But none worked

```
R = Row("id","age","serial")
List=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
sp=spark.createDataFrame([R(i) for i in (List)])
```

Expected:

[please find the expected outout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pACdy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `R(i)` you must use `R(*i)`. This passes individual elements of the inner list to the `Row` object.

In addition to this, `zip` must be applied on the input list to get a list of tuples, like below,

```
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

Full code,

```
R = Row("id","age","serial")
L=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
sp=spark.createDataFrame([R(*i) for i in zip(*L)])
sp.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+------+
| id|age|serial|
+---+---+------+
|  1|  4|     7|
|  2|  5|     8|
|  3|  6|     9|
+---+---+------+
```

Comment: He is asking just for the transpose of your output.

Comment: My bad. Must've overlooked it. I've updated my answer. Thanks.